# How to have a Manifest-declared broadcast receiver communicate with an activity or service?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, accessibility, android-broadcast

This should be obvious but I can't find the solution. Many people have asked it and the reply is usually to just switch to a context-registered receiver instead. I have an accessibility service which needs to be notified when the Manifest-declared receiver picks up something. Obviously this can't be done with an interface since I can't find a way to get the instance of the receiver. Here's some code:

*Manifest*:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
    android:process=":listenerProcess4">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":listenerProcess4">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="roastie_toastie" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*Receiver*:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    BroadcastReceivedListener mBroadcastReceivedListener;

    public void setBroadcastReceivedListener(BroadcastReceivedListener broadcastReceivedListener) {
        mBroadcastReceivedListener = broadcastReceivedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mBroadcastReceivedListener.broadcastReceived();
    }

    public interface BroadcastReceivedListener {
        void broadcastReceived();
    }
}
```

*MyAccessibilityService*:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService implements MyBroadcastReceiver.BroadcastReceivedListener {

    boolean lightsAreOn = true;

    @Override
    public void broadcastReceived() {
        lightsAreOn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what sort of command or message you are sending to the service via this receiver? It will help us to give you relevant suggestions if we have something specific to reference.

Comment: Say that `MyAccessibilityService` implements an interface belonging to `MyBroadcastReceiver`, and inside `onReceive()` I trigger the method of this interface so it can do something inside `MyAccessibilityService`

Comment: "so it can do something" -- can you give us a concrete example? That is what I am seeking.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited the post for an example, but obviously it's not working since I never set the value of the interface in `MyBroadcastReceiver` since I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a couple of times for concrete scenarios, and you did not really provide any, so I am going to answer with an abstract scenario: suppose that your broadcast is designed to send a command to the service.

In that case, you could:

1. Implement a singleton (here called `CommandBus`, for lack of a better idea of a name). Ideally, that singleton would be set up by a dependency inversion framework (e.g., Dagger/Hilt).
2. Have `CommandBus` expose some reactive way to get commands to the service. If you were using Kotlin, that could be a `SharedFlow`. Since you are using Java, that could be an RxJava `Observable`, or perhaps a simple callback.
3. Have `MyAccessibilityService` get access to the `CommandBus` singleton and use whatever you set up in step #2 to find out about commands.
4. Have `CommandBus` expose an API to hand it commands to deliver to the service (e.g., a `sendCommand()` method).
5. Have `MyBroadcastReceiver` get access to the `CommandBus` singleton and call the method from step #4 in `onReceive()`.

At this point, when `MyBroadcastReceiver` receives a broadcast, it tells `CommandBus` to send the command, which then flows over to `MyAccessibilityService`, which goes and does something.

Comment: But everyone keeps saying there are multiple reasons why using singletons is a bad idea. I guess I'll try it out anyway. First order of business is I will have to look up what a `CommandBus` is :)

Comment: @purchaseTest: `CommandBus` is a custom class of your own creation, with the characteristics that I described. "But everyone keeps saying there are multiple reasons why using singletons is a bad idea" -- singletons are unavoidable in Android. Ideally, you manage them with a dependency inversion framework, and you take great care not to introduce a memory leak.